# C++ callback function run time error

Tags: c++, linux, callback, g++

I have a function that accepts function pointer as an argument and calls the function pointer as shown below.

```
int foo (int a, int(*calc)(int))
{
    int y;
    // ....
    // calling calc function via callback
    (*calc)(y);
}
```

The calc function to be called back looks like

```
int calc(int x)
{
    // ....
    cout << x; 
    checkValue(x);
}
```

function `foo` is placed in `a.cpp` and function `calc()` and `checkValue()` are defined in files `b.cpp` and `c.cpp`.  My problem is  `calc()` executes fine until the `cout` statement and fails to call `checkValue()` function. The crash report I received is:

```
symbol lookup error:..... undefined symbol: _ZNSaIcEC1Ev, version GLIBCXX_3.4
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Run it with a debugger and find out **exactly** where it's crashing. It's calling `checkValue()` but crashing elsewhere. Include more of the code from `foo` and include the code for `checkValue()` because it's crashing in one of those functions.

Comment: What version of libstdc++ does it show when you run "ldd -r /path/to/your/programm" or "readelf -d /path/to/your/programm | grep PATH"?

Comment: add an endl; after your cout statement in your calc function.  You may not be seeing this output because you're not flushing the stream.  Or use a debugger to verify you're not reaching the checkValue(x) line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol `_ZNSaIcEC1Ev` is the mangled name for the `std::allocator<char>::allocator()` zero-argument constructor (I determined this using the [`c++filt(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt) program).  The error message "`symbol lookup error:..... undefined symbol`" relates to dynamic linking and has nothing to do with calling a function through a function pointer.

Your error almost certainly lies somewhere else.  You're probably getting confused about the location of the error due to **stdout buffering** -- strings are getting printed to stdout, but you're not seeing them show up because they're getting buffered in memory, and then the program crashes before they're displayed.  To avoid that, you need to make sure to flush the output after every print statement (e.g. by inserting `std::cout << std::endl` or `std::cout << std::flush` or explicitly calling `std::cout.flush()`), or by using `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout`, which is unbuffered by default.

Comment: I tried what you suggest. your idea seem legit. when I flush every cout statement, the program crashes without executing any statement in  the callback. The new error is _ZNKSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEEcvPvEv, version GLIBCXX_3.4.
I will try to check it out. suggestions are encouraged :)

Comment: As u said it was a linking error, It took me quite sometime to figure out the source though. My mistake was attempting  to pass a null pointer to the call back function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int calc(int x){
  cout<< "calc:" << x << endl;
}

int CALC(int x) {
    cout << "CALC: " << x << endl;
}


int foo (int a, int(*callback)(int)){
    cout << "Calling calc on:" << a << endl;
    (*callback)(a);
}

int main() {
    cout << "START" << endl;

    foo(5, calc);
    foo(6, CALC);
}
```

This works fine for me.

```
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
```

Note: I removed your "checkValue(x)" call, the issue could be in there...